# Sort an array of String based on a name pattern

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, comparator

I want to sort an array of strings by whether they contain a custom pattern or not.

I have tried custom sort using comparator, but they all sort based on ascending or descending order. My requirement is as follows:

```
String[] strArr = { "maven", "maven_apache", "java", "multithreading", "java_stream" };
String patternToMatch = "java";
```

Then output should be a sorted array with strings containing the pattern `java` first, followed by the others:

```
String[] strArr = { "java", "java_stream", "maven", "maven_apache", "multithreading" };
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors in this Java code. Are you sure this is the input and the expected output?

Comment: @LutzHorn Corrected

Answer (score 8):

As simple as defining a `Comparator` and sorting the elements based on it:

```
Arrays.sort(strArr, Comparator.comparing(x -> !x.startsWith("java")));
```

Comment: @Eugene Thanks , this helped, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `contains` instead of `startsWith`?

Comment: Was amazed to see this solution :) Works fine in most cases. Only issue I found is when you use text `maven` instead of `java`, it results in `maven, maven_apache, java, multithreading, java_stream` instead of `maven, maven_apache, java, java_stream, multithreading`

Comment: @tobias_k `false` < `true` for `boolean` (or `Boolean`) variables, so if the word `x` starts with `"java"`, `x.startsWith("java")` would return `true`, thus moving the words that start with `"java"` to the end. That's why you need to negate the predicate, and that's why I find this code not very expressive (though it is very short and elegant).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner agreed, takes a bit of fiddling to actually get it; but I got used to it

Comment: @Eugene Yes, it is a matter of *getting used to it*... I also understand it and it's clear to me, but I've seen many junior devs (and some senior devs too) stare at this code for quite some time while scratching their heads... +1 anyways, as elegance always deserves an upvote

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yeah, so what does that have to do with my comment? Just saying that OP is talking about string containing other string in the question, not about strings starting with other strings.

Comment: @Prasann Well, you could still slap on `thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`

Comment: @tobias_k I was reading your comment again and was about to comment exactly about that, sorry, I've misunderstood your comment. I agree with you, it should be `contains` instead of `startsWith` (my explanation above still stands, but it's not for you), or maybe even a `Pattern` should be used, depending on what a *pattern* actually means for the OP.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner when you always restrict the code to what all junior devs will understand for sure, you take away their chance to learn the things they don’t understand yet. For production code, you’d use `static final Comparator<String> JAVA_PREFIX_FIRST = Comparator.comparing(x -> !x.startsWith("java"));` and later-on in the code, `Arrays.sort(strArr, JAVA_PREFIX_FIRST);`. That’s understandable to everyone and the inner workings of the comparator is not different to a library function, you only need to understand what it does, not how it works (unless you’re curious).

Comment: @Holger Absolutely agree, just wanted to make my point clear. I'm not advocating to *not use* advanced features, but to make it clear for code readers and reviewers what the code does instead. And when code is not expressive enough, a comment is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work for you. You can use it to determine if the string starts with "java", then swap it to the first know "non-java" of the array if it returns true.

public boolean startsWith(String prefix, int toffset)

Tests if the substring of this string beginning at the specified index starts with the specified prefix.
Parameters:
prefix - the prefix. toffset - where to begin looking in this string.

Returns:
true if the character sequence represented by the argument is a prefix of the substring of this object starting at index toffset; false otherwise. The result is false if toffset is negative or greater than the length of this String object; otherwise the result is the same as the result of the expression

```
      this.substring(toffset).startsWith(prefix)
```